# What do we mean by “derive full operator of a quantum circuit” and to describe the mapping from input quantum registers to output quantum registers?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

There is a quantum circuit with several Controlled NOT and Controlled swap gates, with two 2-qubit input registers X,Y and two 2-qubit output registers X',Y' where we have to find the mapping of the circuit and what operations it performs.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum computing SE. Could you please add more details, e.g. a circuit picture? Thank you.

Comment: I didnt want to directly ask the question as the guidelines dont allow me but you asked so  i have edited the ques and posted a picture of the ques. You dont need to answer the whole ques just give me an explanation because i am totally new to this and just started.

Comment: @ArpitSingh Why edit the question to make it less informative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 4 qubits, so the "full operator" is only at most a 16x16 matrix that combines all 7 of those multi-qubit gates. You can derive this "full operator" in MATLAB quite easily by using the "kron" function to build up the multi-qubit gates from 1-qubit and 2-qubit gates (2x2 and 4x4 matrices respectively), and then doing matrix multiplication.

As for the second question: "what operation does this circuit implement", this will become easier to answer once you figure out the 16x16 matrix see what it does to the four input  qubits.